# Jquery list nav - Double list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I am getting an error when I try to implement [this plugin](http://www.ihwy.com/labs/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx)? Instead of a single list of tags, 2 of them are appearing. Where could the problem be?

[My page example](http://www.galleriaathena.com/athena/artisti%20e%20opere/new-page-artisti.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one item to check is if div id="demoFour-nav" is in your html twice.
Can you check that your html looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="demo4">
    <h2>Test artisti</h2>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <div id="listWrapper">

        <div id="demoFour-nav" class="listNav">
        </div>

        <ul id="demoFour" class="demo">
            <li class="ln-a"><a href="#">Agizzy</a></li>
            <li class="ln-a"><a href="#">Aiboo</a></li>
```

... etc.

Comment: tried to remove the function demoFour-nav remains only the passive list

Comment: i don't think you should remove it, just make sure there aren't 2 copies of it.